# Apply style to clicked image and not to all

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've 4 images in a page and need to apply the style1 to all of them but when I click in each I need to remove style1 and apply style2 but just to the clicked, the others must be remain with style1. I try with this code but without success:

```
$(document).ready({
  $('img').removeClass();
  $('img').addClass('style1');

  $('img').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass();
    $(this).addClass('style2');
  });
});
```

Any help? What I'm doing wrong? Cheers and thx in advance

Comment: me too - http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/SJW83/

Comment: so what doesn't work?  Did you want the other three images to get style1 back whenever another image is clicked?

Comment: "what am I doing wrong" - not checking for console error messages, most likely, given what @akoptsov spotted in your code... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fully working fiddle, with both once-only and toggle available:

http://jsfiddle.net/46hxR/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      /* To toggle the classes instead of adding, just delete these 3 lines following this comment, then keep reading */
  $('img').addClass('style1');
  $('img').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('style1').addClass('style2');

  /* To toggle the classes instead of just adding, remove this line...
  $('img').toggleClass('style1').toggleClass('style2');
  $('img').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('style1').toggleClass('style2');
  ... And this one too! */
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

have you forgotten the `function()` part in `$(document).ready()` or is it just a misprint?

I have added it and everything seems to work to an extent:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('img').removeClass();
  $('img').addClass('style1');

  $('img').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass();
    $(this).addClass('style2');
  });
});
```

Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/akoptsov/ddFfr/)

Also, if you want to remove `style2` on another click, check the answers above for the usage of `toggleClass()`

Comment: This looks like the only real answer so far.  Good catch.

Comment: that's the trouble with jsfiddle - it encourages you to just post the ready function _body_ , without the rest of the boiler-plate.

Comment: that's why I used `no wrap` when making an example fiddle :)

Answer (score 1):

A slight adjustment, but its basically the same:

```
  $('img').addClass('style1');

  $('img').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('style1').addClass('style2');
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FmCGu/